# How to compile VBScript to contain DLL handlers?

Tags: gcc, dll, vbscript, compilation

I am using VBSedit to compile some VBScripts to .exe. The exe is created fine and shows `MsgBox` and so on. However, once it hits the part where libraries are used and tries to CreateObject it stops working. Obiously, I can run the script from VBSedit because I can add references to the libraries. But I don't know how to compile the executable so it contais the libraries. Any help? Might `gcc` help?

```vb
Sub Main()
   Dim autECLConnMgr, autECLSession, sessionID, actCtx
   Dim myScreenStr, libPath

   'libPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Personal Communications\autcmgr.tlb"
   'Set autECLConnMgr = GetObject(libPath)
   'this does not work

   Set autECLConnMgr = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnMgr")

   ...
   'below here where some tests but it breaks on the lines above
End Sub
```

The error message I get is

> ActiveX component can not create object.

Comment: Make sure that you compile the script to the executable of the same architecture (run `vbsedit 32-bit` for x86 or `vbsedit` for x64) as the ActiveX.

Comment: @omegastripes: Both the VBSedit and the PCOMM are 32 bit versions. That should not be the issue here.

Comment: If you are running the executable on another machine you have to make sure that the COM DLL is registered with the OS before calling the executable. COM registration is on a machine by machine basis and is a prerequisite that must be in place before any call to `CreateObject` for that COM DLL library will function correctly, which includes registering it with the correct subsystem (32 vs 64 bit).

Comment: Some useful information - [Error ASP 0177: 8007007e Server.CreateObject fails for COM DLL](//stackoverflow.com/a/35985827) *(applies to both `Server.CreateObject()` and `CreateObject()` depending on your environment)*.